# django rest framework - allow only certain methods

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a resource where i only want to allow a client to do a post request on the resource, thats why i use

```
class MyViewSet(mixins.CreateModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):
```

in my viewset.

When i do a post request, it works as expected.

When i do a list request, it throws a 405 response, as expected.

When i do a retrieve, put, patch or delete method, it throws a 404 instead of a 405...why?

How can i make every single request return a 405 despite of the post request?

thanks and greetings!

Answer (score 2):

Use **`http_method_names`** attribute

```
class MyViewSet(mixins.CreateModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    http_method_names = ['post']
    # your code
```

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be any reason to use a ViewSet if you only want to support a single action. Instead, use a [CreateApiView](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#createapiview) with a specific URL pointing to it.

Answer (score 1):

If you viewset doesn't have any detail methods, then the drf SimpleRouter will not create any url route for `/api/basename/{id}/`

So Django's url dispatcher will not match those urls at all, and returns a 404.

I don't think it makes sense to return 405 for every single method. That status implies that at least one method should be valid for a specific url.

You could add a dummy detail method, but just hand all requests over to the APIView 405 handler.

I think this should force the router to register detail urls for the viewset, and just return 405 for everything (possibly with the exception of OPTIONS).

```
class MyViewSet(mixins.CreateModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):

    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.http_method_not_allowed(request, *args, **kwargs)
```